# How to query the spring boot repository and get real data, not memory locations

Tags: sql, spring-repositories

I needed to extract data from my repository which could not be extracted using the common conventions afforded by spring boot. I found a solution by sticking the queries inside the repository class like so:

```
@Repository
public interface BarbToiletryOrderRepository extends CrudRepository<BarbToiletryOrder, Integer> {
    @Query(value = "SELECT item_total_cost_us FROM barb_toiletry_order", nativeQuery = true)
    public List<Object[]> findTotalOneRowCost();

    @Query (value = "SELECT id FROM barb_toiletry_order", nativeQuery = true )
    public List<Object[]>findId();
}
```

But then I initiated the queries from within a method of the service class as shown below. So that I could get real data instead of memory locations, I had to come up with strange parsing code for both queries. How could I have avoided all this tweaking? I tried generating "equals() and hashcode()" as well as "toString()" code to no avail.

```
 List<Object[]> costGrandTallyList = barbToiletryOrderRepository.findTotalOneRowCost();
 List<Object[]> idList = barbToiletryOrderRepository.findId();

      for (Object[] insideArray : costGrandTallyList){
            String useArray = Arrays.toString(insideArray);
            StringBuffer ta = new StringBuffer(useArray);
            ta.delete(useArray.length() - 1, useArray.length());
            ta.delete(0, 1);
            Double tempDec = Double.valueOf(String.valueOf(ta));

            String useArray2 = Arrays.toString(idList.get(i));
            StringBuffer ta2 = new StringBuffer(useArray2);
            ta2.delete(useArray2.length() - 1, useArray2.length());
            ta2.delete(0,1);
            Integer intVal = Integer.valueOf(String.valueOf(ta2));

            costGrandTally = costGrandTally + tempDec;

        }
```